# Searching for an image by src in Selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

I have to write a Selenium test and I need to get an element by the src as  there is no ID for it.

How do I go about doing something like `//div[@id='content-inner']` but with `@src='../mapshop/images/buy.png'`  or even better using a contains 'buy.png'?

I've tried testing if the image is there but, `selenium.IsElementPresent("//img [@src='../mapshop/images/buy.png']")` but that just returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.

Very simple. Needed to specify the full image url not just the src

```
selenium.IsElementPresent("//img [@src='http://dev.emapsite.com/QA/mapshop/images/edit.png']")  
returns true.
```

Comment: Interestingly Firefox seems to complain about getting and element by it's src  whewre IE handles it perfectly.

Comment: Better way to do it is: selenium.Click("//img[contains(@src,'edit.png')]");