# Working with WebDriver (findElement function)

Tags: webdriver

I'm writing a program in Java that submits a form using WebDriver. There is a method findElement that allows you to select elements using class name, css selector, id, link text, name, partial link text, tag name, or xpath.

Here's the button that I want to select:

```
<div class="editable" style = "width:82px;float:right;margin-right:10px;">
<a href="#" onclick="$('order_form').submit(); return false;" class="btn">
    <img class="btn" src="/myhuds/images/rd_images/btn_place_order.gif" alt="Place Order" width="82" height="17" border="0">
</a>
</div>
```

I can't use class name because there are multiple buttons on the page. Any ideas on how I might go about using the findElement method to select this button?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying that now; thanks!

Comment: You can use the src to find the image.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577134/searching-for-an-image-by-src-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. You can add some browser plugin to get XPath.

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your XPath"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the button (may be to all buttons in your page) and find as -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Your ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS selectors`. You can find a short explanation here [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), and couple examples here :[Examples](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Therefore, try to use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...));`

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case you can search based on img @alt attribute using XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Place Order']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

With the available DOM Structure Generate CSS Selector for the "Place Order"
Image

css=a[onclick*='order_form']  > img[src*='btn_place_order.gif']

Then Perform Click on "Place Order" Image.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[onclick*='order_form']  > img[src*='btn_place_order.gif']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Following example should help:

Html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"

<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="page-header">Login</h1>
    <ul class="errors"></ul>
    <div>
        <form class="login-form" action="checkLogin.html" method="post">
            <label for="username-field">Username1</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="username-field" />
            <br />
            <label for="password-field">Password1</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="password-field" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form class="login-form" action="checkLogin.html" method="post">
            <label for="username-field">Username2</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="username-field" />
            <br />
            <label for="password-field">Password2</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="password-field" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To locate the input field for Password1 :

```
WebElement passwordField1: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:nth-child(3) .password-field"));
```

To locate the input field for Password2 :

```
WebElement passwordField2: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:nth-child(4) .password-field"));
```

Learn more about nth-child() selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).